# R: venn.diagram font size equivalent to ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, venn-diagram

Is there any way to choose same font size in venn_diagram diagram than in ggplot2 charts? In venn_diagram the font size is determined by the percents. Thanks a lot!

For example, I have venn diagram like this

```
set1 <- paste(rep("word_" , 200) , sample(c(1:1000) , 200 , replace=F) , sep="")
set2 <- paste(rep("word_" , 200) , sample(c(1:1000) , 200 , replace=F) , sep="")
set3 <- paste(rep("word_" , 200) , sample(c(1:1000) , 200 , replace=F) , sep="")

venn.diagram(
  x = list(set1, set2, set3),
  category.names = c("Set 1" , "Set 2 " , "Set 3"),
  main = "Figure 1",
  main.cex = 1.8,
  filename = '#14_venn_diagramm.png',
  output=TRUE
)
```

Then I have a ggplot2 chart like that:

```
data <- data.frame(
  name=c("A","B","C","D","E") ,  
  value=c(3,12,5,18,45)
  )

tiff("test.tiff", units="in", width=9.9, height=3.3, res=600)
ggplot(data, aes(x=name, y=value)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 8)) +
  theme(text = element_text(family = "Times New Roman")) +
  labs(title = "Figure 2.", y = NULL, x= NULL, fill = NULL)
dev.off()
```

So is there any way to determine, that both titles are in same size (in venn diagram the size is main.cex = 1.8 and in ggplot-chart the size = 8

Comment: Provide example data and code, what packages are you using for venn?

Comment: I'd plot without titles then use patchwork/cowplot, and add titles separately, so they all have the same style titles.

Comment: Thanks! What about if I want to determine also e.g. venn diagram category names font size and ggplot bar chart y and x axis font size? Is there any convenient way to make all the text in the graphs the same size?

Comment: Another option is to use ggplot based Venn diagrams.

Comment: Thanks; I know that but I prefer venn_diagram function.